# Multidimensional numpy.ndarray from multi-indexed pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I want to produce a 3-dimensional numpy.ndarray from a multi-indexed pandas.DataFrame. More precisely, say I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '1' , 1, 10], [1, '2', 2, 20], [2, '1', 5, 30]], columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 't'])
df = df.set_index(['x','y'])
df
```

which gives me

```
        z  t
  x  y
  1  1  1 10
     2  2 20
  2  1  5 30
```

and I want to write a function which returns, with the above argument, the numpy.ndarray

```
  [[[1, 10],
    [2, 20]],
   [[5, 30],
    [NaN, NaN]]]
```

Pandas multi-index looks like a substitute for multidimensional arrays, but it does not provide (or at least does not document) ways to go back and forth...

Thanks.

Comment: `df.unstack().stack(dropna=False).to_numpy()`

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work: this returns a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.to_xarray().to_array().values.transpose(1,2,0)

>>[[[ 1. 10.]
  [ 2. 20.]]

 [[ 5. 30.]
  [nan nan]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! So xarray is yet another library on top of numpy and pandas, which has to patch the deficiencies of pandas? PS: I'll upvote your answer when I have enough reputation.

Comment: yes, it's a different data structure. more info [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-data-structures-of-xarray-80bab8094efa)

Comment: note the `transpose` is just to get the values in the order you specified.